# What is the best TV to have in a foley stage?

Tags: studio, television, noise, foley

Hi! I am building a new studio dedicated to sound design, and I was wondering how to choose a TV to have in the control room and in the foley room. I've seen some LG LCD TVs that have a very good price, but I have no idea if they make any unacceptable noise (like those unbearable hums generated by some monitors). Which is more "silent" when muted: PLASMA, LCD, or LED? Are there any specific brands that are known to make more noise than others? Is there anyway noise from TVs can be reduced or eliminated?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't recommend you a tv, but I can tell you plasmas will hum when showing whites and bright colors.

Comment: Ok, so no plasmas in the studio! Thanks! Do you know anything about LCD or LED Tvs? Can I trust them?

Comment: make sure whatever you do use you do a sync check so you know what the performer is seeing is in sync with the audio!

http://www.pharoahaudio.com/syncheckproducthomepage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't go the projector route, I've seen an LCD encased in plexiglass, attached to a lazy susan. They didn't have to worry about dust in the TV or a wild prop ricocheting off the screen. It kept the room quiet, and they could position it to be viewable from anywhere. Quite clever really.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution. I find it really great! Isn't there any problem of heat with the encased TV? I imagine we would have to leave some openings for it to "breathe", or not? If there's no problem with this I'd love to do it this way, because of the ricochet and dust!

Comment: Yeah, didn't get to inspect the mechanics of it, but if it was a 47" tv, the case was probably 60". Having a small air vent with a replaceable filter in place would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The very best solution would be to use a video projector, in another room, isolated from the foley stage.

Comment: That's a very good idea! The problem is that we have small spaces and no way to use a video projector. That would've been great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Our LCD Sony 37" is very quiet, but not completely silent.  Recently we have switched to using VGA LCD monitors, and trying out different brands, but they all seem to be really quiet, even after hours of work, just avoid anything with a fan in it.

Comment: I like very much that solution! I don't know if there are 42" monitors, I imagine there are. Thank you! I'll investigate!

Answer (score 1):

I ditched all ideas of TV's in my studio pretty much the same day I tried them. CRT:s was sending massive interferences to the mikes, the plasmas I've seen was buzzing, and the LCD:s had, for some reason, a lot of delay.

I use LCD-monitors in my studio for all monitoring, be it the two from the computer or through the Video Out from my Matrox-card via a VGA split-box to all video playback. They do give off a very low pulse-sound when dormant, but are virtually dead silent while active. Though I do use Samsung's more expensive models, they do have had a few year since they left the factory, and as such they do have a florescent light backlight. On paper, that would mean potential statics through microphones, but frankly I have never ever noticed anything like that though any of my ADR-mikes, normally Sennheiser MKH416, MKH 40, Oktava 012 or Schoeps CMIT 5. Modern LED-backlight LCD displays have, at least on paper, none of that problem whatsoever, and my home monitor, a BENQ, seems to confirm that.

Comment: Come to think of it, I have a faint memory of the plasmas giving off possibly as much interference as the CRTs as well? I do like the blacks and luminance of plasma, but I truly loath the fuzzy burn-in-happy picture and short lifespan, so I wouldn't chose it anyway :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response! I've been looking for LCD monitors, but they seem tyo get really expensive over the 26". The problem is I´m looking for a BIG screen for the foley stage, and another one for the screenings, so I wan my foley artists and my clients to be able to see each detail (as much as possible). I looked for a 42" LCD monitor and it was really expensive, so I think I'll have to find my way out with the LCD TVs. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a 46" Sony Led and it has been working pretty well. I haven't noticed any noise.